# R: labeling axes on a plot

Tags: r, visualization

```
       date = c("11/22", "11/23", "11/24")
       date = as.factor(date)
       temperature = c("80", "90", "100")

       plot(date, temperature)
```

My question is, how can I specify xlim for this plot since the x-axis variable is a factor? Furthermore, if I would like to color-code a single point on my plot, say, I would want the temperature for 11/23 to be colored green. How can I do that?

Comment: [**First hit**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+plot+color+single+point)

Comment: Why are you plotting dates as a factor? Have you considered something like this?: `date <- as.Date(c("2014-11-22", "2014-11-23", "2014-11-24"))`

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
plot(date, temperature, xaxt="n", col=c("black", "green", "black"))
axis(1, at=date, label=as.character(date))
```

Alternatively you could also add color points with: `points(date[2], temperature[2], col="green"`.